# Cannot access Vue CLI inside docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js

Based on this guide:

https://shekhargulati.com/2019/01/18/dockerizing-a-vue-js-application/

I have created a sample VueJS app and created a docker image:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

based on the below Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM node:10.15.0

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli
# start app
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

Next I run a docker container with:

```
docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app -v /usr/src/app/node_modules -p 5000:5000 myapp
```

and get this (successfull) output:

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 4644ms                                                                                 4:05:10 PM

No type errors found
No lint errors found
Version: typescript 3.4.3, tslint 5.15.0
Time: 4235ms

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 

  It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
  Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

I then try to access the application from my browser on: http://localhost:5000/ but I just get a **The connection was reset** error.

I have also tried to inspect the port information on the running container with:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
755d2745bce2        myapp               "npm run serve"     22 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   confident_mirzakhani
$ docker port confident_mirzakhani
5000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:5000
```

But that basically confirms the port info I passed to the run command.

Any suggestion on how to access the VueJS application in the container from the browser on my host?

Comment: according to the posted output app is running on 8080 !

Comment: Yes of course I tried that but its not running there either. And if you read a bit further down in the output it also says: "Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/"

Comment: you need to map the same port that the app is running on, so either use
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve", "--port", "5000"] in the Dockerfile
or change the port mapping in docker run command
-p 8080:8080

Comment: perfect that was it!